# Unicorn Install Script with RVM -- which executable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-10.04, unicorn

I am trying to get an init script running for unicorn (on Ubuntu) with unicorn installed as a gem:

/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@polco/bin/unicorn

My init script is:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn web server
# Description:       starts unicorn
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@polco/bin/unicorn
DAEMON_OPTS="-c /home/deployer/shop/current/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
NAME=unicorn_rails
DESC=unicorn_rails
PID=/home/deployer/shop/shared/pids/unicorn.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    sleep 1
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
        kill -HUP `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The whole operation seems fragile to me with the rvm executable. Does rvm have something like $CURRENT_RVM_PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.k. i solved this for me. I stopped caring if I was root or not and decided to run this as, ironically, the user 'passenger' and I needed to run unicorn_rails.

here is my startup script:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn web server
# Description:       starts unicorn
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#DAEMON=/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@polco/bin/unicorn
DAEMON=/home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/unicorn_rails
DAEMON_OPTS="-c /home/passenger/polco/current/config/unicorn_tacitus.rb -E production -D"


NAME=unicorn_rails
DESC=unicorn_rails
PID=/home/passenger/polco/shared/pids/unicorn.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    sleep 1
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
        kill -HUP `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

To execute this -- I now have the simple capistrano task:

```
  desc "restart unicorn"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{current_path}/unicorn_exec restart"
  end

  after "deploy:restart","unicorn:restart"
```

The last question I is why I have to restart unicorn_rails. I thought I could reload via: kill -HUP `cat $PID`, but everything only works if I restart.

Answer (score 1):

Since google might find this question for other people, here is my unicorn restart script I'm using on 3 different servers.  I just need to add USR2 The repo is called [eunic](https://github.com/pjammer/eunic/blob/master/eunic) and i may hack on this later.

All that to say, here is another way to do it.